# Referring to a value in a cell where the row or column is a variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I have tried multiple ways to refer to a specific cell within the whole sheet where the row and/or column is a variable but I cannot figure out the syntax.

Right now, I am specifically trying to save a value from a cell into a variable and then perform a vlookup using the value in that cell. In this bit of code, the row number (RowNum) will change as a loop iterates but the column will remain the same.

```
Dim ColNum As Integer       'column on production report
Dim RowNum As Integer       'row on production report
Dim CopySheet As Worksheet  'sheet to copy from
Dim vlookupValue As Variant 'variable to store a lookup value for a vlookup
Dim responseType As String  'Type of report on caller

RowNum = 2

Set CopySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UsedCases")

vlookupValue = CopySheet.Range.Cells(RowNum, "N").Value
responseType = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(vlookupValue, Dispositions, 3)
```

I declared the variable "vlookupValue" as a variant because it will sometimes be a string and sometimes be a number.

I also tried the vlookupValue code as this:

```
vlookupValue = CopySheet.Range.Cells(RowNum, 14).Value
```

There is something I am not getting about the syntax when it comes to referring to cells on the whole sheet.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, try `vlookupValue = CopySheet.Cells(RowNum, "N").Value` or   `vlookupValue = CopySheet.Range("N" & RowNum).Value`. Both ways should work.

Comment: Thank you so much--I will try that tomorrow--it's been driving me crazy!

Comment: Didn't come 'tomorrow', yet?

Comment: LOL I did try it and it worked!!!